# Latex Figure Position

Tags: floats, positioning

In latex, how can we ensure that a figure is placed nearest to the place where it was defined or before?

The issue I'm getting is that sometimes many of many figures are getting on the same page which make it very confusing

Comment: You can use the option `[H]` to place the figure exactly where you enter it in the document.

Comment: Have a look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15717) and it's linked Q and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/15717)

Comment: Dowvoter: Please have patience/courage to leave a comment for clarification or atleast place duplicates here.